# UUID Keeps returning the value 1 when converting to string

Tags: java, android, mobile, uuid

I've included the source I have been working on and I am at wit's end trying to figure this out. Using SQLite on Java(Android) I'm creating a table for every recording you input. Except I keep hitting the same road block. UUID keeps returning the value 1 for me and then causing the application to crash. Setting break points at every single place that ID is initialized throughout the application and comes that when I call UUID.randomUUID() then converting it to string it returns 1 every single time. Any Idea?

```
public class ToDo {

private UUID id;
private String title;
private String genre;
private String comment;
private float rating;
private boolean complete;

public ToDo() {
    id = UUID.randomUUID();
}

public ToDo(String id, String title,String genre,String comment,float rating, int complete) {
    this.id = UUID.fromString(id);
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.rating = rating;

    if(complete==1)
        this.complete=true;
    else
        this.complete=false;
}

public ToDo(String title,String genre,String comment,float rating, boolean complete) {
    id = UUID.randomUUID();

    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.complete = complete;
}

public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}


}

import java.util.UUID;

public class MovieActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ToDo toDo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie);




    UUID id = (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("id");

    if(id != null){
        toDo = ToDoList.get(this.getApplicationContext()).getToDo(id);
    }

    if(toDo !=null){
        titleField.setText(toDo.getTitle());
        genre.setText(toDo.getGenre());
        comment.setText(toDo.getComment());
        ratingBar.setRating(toDo.getRating());
        completeCheckBox.setChecked(toDo.isComplete());

        addEditButton.setText(R.string.update);
        addEditButton.setOnClickListener(new OnUpdateButtonClick());

    }else{
        toDo = new ToDo();
        addEditButton.setOnClickListener(new OnAddButtonClick());
    }


}


private class OnAddButtonClick implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ToDoList toDoList = ToDoList.get(getApplicationContext());
        toDoList.addTodo(toDo);
        finish();
    }
}

private class OnUpdateButtonClick implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ToDoList toDoList = ToDoList.get(getApplicationContext());
        toDoList.updateToDo(toDo);
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There is a crazy amount of code here if the problem is just "uuid keeps returning 1". Please cut it down to a [mcve].

Comment: Cut out the completely irrelevant information.